# Usuario final de un software Gtk+ en Windows

Tags: windows

Tengo un software instalado que se niega testarudamente a dignarse arrancar. Me han sugerido que investigue sobre posibles dependencias de librerías externas sin resolver, pero la verdad es que no es mi campo.

Se que es posible que el programa funciona de maneras *curiosas* (empaquetando las librerías como recursos y descomprimiéndolas en un archivo temporal, por ejemplo), pero tengo esperanzas en que no sea así y se limite a utilizar enlazado dinámico.

#### ¿ De que herramientas dispongo **en Windows** para comprobar si un determinado ejecutable puede localizar todas las `.dll` de las que depende ?

Preferentemente que estén disponibles en el propio sistema *de fábrica*; si no queda mas remedio, pues herramientas gratuitas.

Comment: Te la he editado un poco, para acomodarla algo a las políticas del sitio. A ver si tienes suerte y alguien te responde :-)

Comment: Esto: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ me ha salvado la vida muchas veces. El secreto es levantar con esta herramienta el ejecutable y darle `<F7>` o profile de ejecución, luego analizar todas las dependencias que no se han podido encotrar.

Comment: @Trauma Te lo agradezco, a veces cuesta un poco leer todas las políticas de un sitio, y lo debería hacer. Yo realmente no soy el usuario final, solo quiero crear un instalador de mi programa que resuelva las dependencias en la maquina donde se esté instalando. Gracias!